# Magento 2.1 - Cancel an order [ configurable product ] issue

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, orders, magento-2.1, magento2.1.0

I'm so confused about cancelling orders in Magento.

I made an issue post in Magento2 github repository explaining my problems.

**1st issue :**

**NB :** All the products are configurable

The test products :

**Product 1 :**

```
Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie
SKU: MH01-XS-Black
Color: Black 
Size: XS
```

**Product 2 :**

```
Chaz Kangeroo Hoodie
SKU: MH01-M-Orange
Color: Orange 
Size: M
```

1. Add the 2 configurable products above to the cart [product 1 qty 2
   product 2 qty 3]
2. Place the order Invoice & ship partially the order
3. Cancel the order

Magento still shows "Cancel button" after i canceled the order
When i click on Cancel again, it returns to the old state

**See the video**
https://youtu.be/hA7Ov6t3P-Q

For the other issues :

[#5313](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5313)